# Docker says "...: Already exists" even though image has been removed beforehand

Tags: docker, docker-registry, docker-image

Just in the process of learning Docker. Tried to run the hello-world example:

```
# docker run hello-world
```

Worked.

Removed the image using

```
# docker image rm -f <image-id>
```

Worked.

```
# docker images
```

Shows no images.

Now, if I try to run the hello-world example again, it shows this:

[image]

It mentions:

```
2db29710123e: Already exists
```

Does this mean, the image already exists on the local host machine, or the image does exist on the Docker Registry, and this is a new pull?

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Docker says that `2db29710123e: Already exists`, yes, it already exists on your local machine. It doesn't exist as part of the `hello-world` image though, because you force-removed that beforehand. However, why did you have to force-remove it in the first place? Why wasn't a regular remove enough? Here is the message it shows, when running `docker image rm hello-world`:

> Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to remove repository reference "hello-world" (must force) - container 4d198a310ed5 is using its referenced image feb5d9fea6a5

This means you still have a container (from the previous hello-world test) which references that image. So when you force-remove, the image (tag or label) is removed from `docker images`, but the underlying data is still there, locally, because of the existing container.

However, if you remove the container (with `docker container rm` or `docker container prune` for example) before running the hello-world test again, you will pull the image from the repository, because it doesn't exist locally anymore. And if you remove the container before removing the image, you won't need the force-remove anymore, either.

Comment: I pruned the container and now [root@localhost vroot1]# docker container prune
WARNING! This will remove all stopped containers.
Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] y
Deleted Containers:
de5f3d0548d36cd6f4fa36bc1021b198cb888d650c652449976c556b3b825c1c
d44702dacce76958e5062790d188e9ba14683214137daef1c5513f3085cafe46
ce052aa380d39cc28800696ef9bd0376827aa3ddd0c3a71f05fc7630cc8591c5
469cd1de......................5e058e212434d0f8bb4e21f7da5db1a07322d61841645173443175f28933b4a939acf1ebb8ffbb1d01fe67ab867a8bf5ec0359900e8a47cc8c220dd28e3787bf664e04c13c4b

Total reclaimed space: 589.1kB

Comment: I am way both the above solutions worked. Testing again.
I had run
# docker run hello-world
did run successfully, however, when I run the
# docker container ls
it does not show any running containers, however, the image does exist on the local machine.
Now, I tried clearing the image without the -f and was removed successfully

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong:
when I use the  # docker run hello-world, a container shud be spun up along with the pull of the image. 
If above is correct, I do not see the container when I run the # docker container ls.

Comment: using the -a switch I do see that the hello-world container did exit as below:
[root@localhost vroot1]# docker container ls -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE         COMMAND    CREATED         STATUS                     PORTS     NAMES
0d15f9e9cd29   hello-world   "/hello"   4 minutes ago   Exited (0) 4 minutes ago             pedantic_haslett
[root@localhost vroot1]# docker container ls
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
[root@localhost vroot1]#

Answer (score 2):

You have to first stop and remove the docker container using the image using below code:

```
docker kill <container-id> # kills the container

docker rm <container-id> # remove container using hello-world image
```

Then, finally you can remove the image.

```
docker image rm hello-world  # remove the hello-world image
```

Comment: The order doesn't even matter. :) As long as there is no reference anymore once the hello-world test is being run again. You can remove the container and then remove the image or force-remove the image and then remove the container.